# Dedekind's theorem on an integrally closed algebra over a commutative ring without Axiom of Choice

Tags: commutative-algebra, axiom-of-choice

**Motivation**
This question came from my efforts to solve [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155392/existence-of-valuation-rings-in-an-algebraic-function-field-of-one-variable) presented by Andre Weil in 1951.

Can we prove the following theorem without Axiom of Choice?
If the answer is affirmative, by using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170922/krull-akizuki-theorem-without-axiom-of-choice), we can get many examples of Dedekind domains without using Axiom of Choice.
[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170605/dedekinds-theorem-on-a-weakly-artinian-integrally-closed-domain-without-axiom-o) is a related question.

**Theorem**
Let $A$ be a commutative ring.
Let $B$ be an integrally closed $A$-algebra.
Suppose $B/fB$ has a composition series as an $A$-module for every non-zero element $f$ of $B$.
Then the following assertions hold.

(1) Every ideal of $B$ is finitely generated.

(2) Every non-zero prime ideal of $B$ is maximal.

(3) Every non-zero ideal of $B$ is invertible.

(4) Every non-zero ideal of $B$ has a unique factorization as a product of prime ideals.

**EDIT**
[Why worry about the axiom of choice?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22927/why-worry-about-the-axiom-of-choice/)

Comment: Why are you asking a string of very closely related questions about whether theorems from commutative algebra hold without choice?

Comment: I tried to solve the following problem presented by Weil. Most of my questions related AC came from my efforts to solve it. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155392/existence-of-valuation-rings-in-an-algebraic-function-field-of-one-variable

Answer (score 1):

We use the definitions of my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170234/nilpotency-of-the-jacobson-radical-of-an-artinian-ring-without-axiom-of-choice).

**Definition 1**
Let $A$ be a commutative ring.
Let $B$ be a commutative $A$-algebra.
Suppose $leng_A B$ is finite.
Then we say $B$ is an Artinian $A$-algebra.

**Lemma 1**
Let $A$ be a commutative ring.
Let $B$ be an Artinian $A$-algebra.
Let $\Lambda$ be nonempty set of ideals of $B$.
Then there exist a maximal element and a minimal element in $\Lambda$.

Proof:
We note that every ideal of $B$ can be regarded canonically as an A-module.
Let $r = sup$ {$leng_A I; I \in \Lambda$}.
Since $r$ is finite, there exists $I \in \Lambda$ such that $r = leng$ $I$.
By Lemma 4 of my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170234/nilpotency-of-the-jacobson-radical-of-an-artinian-ring-without-axiom-of-choice), $I$ is a maximal element of $\Lambda$.

The existence of a minimal element is proved similarly.
**QED**

**Lemma 2**
Let $A$ be a commutative ring.
Let $B$ be an Artinian $A$-algebra.
Then $leng_B B$ is finite, namely $B$ is an Artinian ring as defined in Definition 1 in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170605/dedekinds-theorem-on-a-weakly-artinian-integrally-closed-domain-without-axiom-o).

Proof:
Let $\Lambda$ be the set of ideals $I$ of $B$ such that $leng_B I$ is finite.
Since $0 \in \Lambda$, $\Lambda$ is not empty.
By Lemma 1, there exists a maximal element $I \in \Lambda$.
Suppose $I \neq B$.
Then, by Lemma 1, there exists an ideal $J$ of $B$ such that $I \subset J$ and $J/I$ is a simple $B$-module.
Since $leng_B J = leng_B I + 1$, $J \in \Lambda$.
This is a contradiction.
Hence $B = I$.
**QED**

**Definition 2**
Let $A$ be a commutative ring.
Let $B$ be a commutative $A$-algebra.
Suppose $leng_A B/fB$ is finite of for every non-zero element $f \in B$.
Then we say $B$ is a weakly Artinian $A$-algebra.
By Lemma 2, $B$ is a [weakly Artinian ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170605/dedekinds-theorem-on-a-weakly-artinian-integrally-closed-domain-without-axiom-o).

**Proof of the title theorem**
By Lemma 2, $B$ is a weakly Artinian ring.
Hence the assertions of the title theorem follow immediately from Lemma 2 and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170605/dedekinds-theorem-on-a-weakly-artinian-integrally-closed-domain-without-axiom-o).
**QED**