# Does $R[[x]] \cong S[[x]]$ imply $R\cong S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, formal-power-series

Let $R,S$ be commutative unitary rings. Is it true that

> $$R[[x]] \cong S[[x]] \quad \Rightarrow \quad  R\cong S.$$

Here by $R[[x]], S[[x]]$ I mean the ring of formal power series and the isomorphisms as isomorphisms of rings.

In fact, in this question [Does $R[x] \cong S[x]$ imply $R \cong S$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13504/does-rx-cong-sx-imply-r-cong-s) the answer for the polynomial ring is negative and I became curious about the formal power series case.

Comment: not an answer, but [here](https://msp.org/pjm/1972/41-2/pjm-v41-n2-p23-s.pdf) is a paper from around the same time as the [cited](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-034-01/S0002-9939-1972-0294325-3/S0002-9939-1972-0294325-3.pdf) one. The result was "author does not know a counterexample."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not true.

An explicit counterexample is given on p. 154 of the paper [*On power-invariance*](https://msp.org/pjm/1975/61-1/pjm-v61-n1-p17-s.pdf), by Eloise A. Hamann,     Pacific J. Math., Volume 61, Number 1 (1975), 153-159.
The example was given by Andy Magid at the   Commutative  Algebra   Conference  in  June   of  1974, based on Hochster's counterexample for polynomial rings.

---

More precisely, [Hochster's counterexample](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-034-01/S0002-9939-1972-0294325-3/S0002-9939-1972-0294325-3.pdf) provides (using hairy ball theorem) a projective non-free module $P$ over the commutative ring $A = \Bbb R[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$ such that $A^3 \cong A \oplus P$ as $A$-modules.

Let $R$ be the complete symmetric algebra of the $A$-modules $P$, i.e. the completion  of  the symmetric  algebra $S_A(P)$ with  respect  to  the  ideal  generated  by $P$.
Let $S := A[[X,Y]]$.
Then, one can show that 
$$R[[T]] \cong A[[X,Y,Z]] \cong S[[T]]$$ as rings (not necessarily as topological rings), but 
$$R \not \cong A[[X,Y]] = S.$$

---

However, theorem 4 in Hamann's paper states that if $R$ has finitely many maximal ideals, then 
$R[\![x]\!] \cong S[\![x]\!] \implies R \cong S$, for every commutative ring $S$.

Moreover, theorem 1.4 in Joong Ho Kim's 1974 paper [*Power invariant rings*](https://msp.org/pjm/1974/51-1/pjm-v51-n1-p20-s.pdf) shows that the same property holds if $R$ has a nilpotent Jacobson radical (i.e. the intersection $J$ of all maximal ideals of $R$ satisfies $J^n=0$ for some $n>0$). For instance, this holds if $R$ is [artinian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170234/nilpotency-of-the-jacobson-radical-of-an-artinian-ring-without-axiom-of-choice) (e.g. a field)  or [semiprimitive](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/6/) (e.g. $\Bbb Z$).

Comment: Wow, that is quite a complete answer. Thank you very much.